# UML : The use inheritance does not pose a problem in the database

Tags: uml, class-diagram

What is the good way to model this case, in my class diagram I have a class question that will have a type either (QCM - coding) and in each type I have defferents properties.

[image]

if I made the inheritance between the class question and the type is that it will work in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a class question that will have a type either (QCM - coding) and in each type I have defferents properties.

Because of the multiplicity 1 in your relations it is mandatory for a `type_question` instance to be associated to an instance of *libre* and *codage* (and probably *qcm*).

To indicate a `type_question` is one of them it is better to have for instance :

[image: class diagram]

where `type_question` is an abstract class.

The attribute *contenu* could depend on the type of the question, perhaps to use a 'standard' attribute is not the best way. I do not propose to move it in the sub classes of `type_question` because of the multiplicities 0..n indicating a given instance of `type_question` can be associated to several instances of `question`.

---

> if I made the inheritance between the class question and the type is that it will work in the database

Even without considering the database to have `question` inheriting `type_question` is incompatible with the fact a given instance of `type_question` can be associated to several instances of `question`, and also incompatible with my proposal above.

Supposing you have anyway that inheritance if I am not wrong when you will consider the database (you do not say if SQL etc) the inheritance disappears and is managed as a relation like currently or including the inherited behaviors in the inheriting class.

Comment: Why do you answer a "question" that is essentially not intelligible and that you didn't manage to make intelligible despite your edits?

Comment: @GerdWagner To help the OP. Your question is quite strange too ^^

Comment: @GerdWagner I edited just to put the picture visible yes. But if you are enough sure to be able to make the question better without taking the risk to not follow the initial meaning, just edit it, I do not 'own' it ...

Comment: @GerdWagner as you see I answer you, even if nothing obliges me, and this despite a certain aggressiveness in your question

Comment: thank you bruno for your answer on the other hand if I delete the class type_question and I've inherited the 3 type directly by the class question it will be fine too !

Comment: @Mojackoo you cannot inherits the 3 types, if you do that you say question is a qcm and is a libre and is a codage at the same time, and this is false

Comment: @bruno the best way is to use an abstract class   _type_question_ and inherits the 3 types and in the dev part we can use the factory pattern to return the right instance when creating a new question